# add directory to /opt

Tags: linux

I bought a software for my job which is needed I create a directory in /opt so that I could import licenses of software and launch my project,
the thing is /opt is restricted by admin and permissions have been dedicated to root.
Is there anyway I could mkdir my folder there?
cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you have root access to the machine (usually via `sudo`), you cannot.

Try either:

```
sudo -i
```

..or:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/thedirectoryname
```

Both require your users password, the first would give you a terminal running as root, the second would simply make the directory.

If this doesn't work (which is very likely), you would need the system's admin to either give you access, or create the directory for you.

Comment: yep,I tried but doesn't work unless I am allowed to execute the command as root

Comment: dbr : sudo -i rather than sudo su - seems neater....

Comment: @Rob: And less prone to PAM errors.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) if you're root admin user has enabled it for you.

If not, and the software you require isn't [propietary software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_software), you may be able to change the source and/or configuration files to get it to point to another location.  It may even be an option as part of the install process, but without knowing what the software is, difficult to say with certainty.

Comment: the matter is he wont enable it for me,that s why i m looking for an alternative